# ITextSharp C# Filling PDF with Isolated Storage Stream always results in unreadable PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, isolatedstorage

Okay so I have been banging my head over this for the past 4 hours. I have a relatively simple block of code and no matter what I try the pdf files are always corrupt. I am using iTextSharp and have tried every version from oldest to newest. Any level insight would be greatly appriciated!

Below is my code.

```
        var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\PDF\form_controller.pdf");
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, Ext.Storage.isoStore)) {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Name", "A cool name");

                stamper.FormFlattening = true;

                stamper.Close();
            }

        }

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.pdf", FileMode.Open, Ext.Storage.isoStore))
            {


                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\PDF\file.pdf", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[isoStream.Length];
                    isoStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)isoStream.Length);
                    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
          }
```

Comment: Change the file mode to just create. It would help to post the pdf.

Comment: I can only test is on the desktop but it all worked for me. I don't know what `Ext.Storage.isoStore` is so I changed it to `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()` but otherwise it worked. Also, instead of messing around with arrays there's a really handle `CopyTo` method you can just use, `isoStream.CopyTo(file);`